# Android onDraw never called

Tags: android, view, android-custom-view

I have a custom linear layout from which I extend. I have already called setWIllNotCacheDrawing but it wont work. Here is my Class:

```
public class ClippedLinearLayout extends LinearLayout {

public ClippedLinearLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.setWillNotCacheDrawing(false);
}

public ClippedLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    this.setWillNotCacheDrawing(false);
}

public ClippedLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.setWillNotCacheDrawing(false);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    Log.e("clipped?", "clipped?);
    Path mPath = new Path();
    mPath.addCircle(50, 50, 50, Path.Direction.CCW);
    canvas.clipPath(mPath, Region.Op.INTERSECT);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}

}
```

Comment: override `draw(Canvas)` or `dispatchDraw(Canvas)`, make sure to call `super(canvas)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're extending a ViewGroup, and sometimes by default they won't draw.  Have you tried calling [View.setWillNotDraw(false)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setWillNotDraw(boolean)) in your constructor?